# java + install only jdk1.6.0 + for WIN32 XP

Tags: java

from my PC I have the following

```
 java -version
 java version "1.6.0_05"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_05-b13)
 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b19, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and under:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java
```

I have only:

```
 jre1.6.0_05
```

my question is that I need also directory jdk1.6.0 
under C:\Program Files\Java

is it possible to install this java only for jdk1.6.0 and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) download JDK and install on your pc.

Comment: Windows x86 76.66 MB    jdk-6u25-windows-i586.exe 
Windows Intel Itanium 67.27 MB    jdk-6u25-windows-ia64.exe 
Windows x64 
my qeastion How to know which of is fit for my XP win?

Comment: You should first try:Windows x86 76.66 MB jdk-6u25-windows-i586.exe. In my pc I have this. Choose it based on pc configuration.

Comment: after I run the program to install the java I get error about temp file internet?

Comment: @jon: whats the complete error? Are you sure its because of jdk?

Comment: @jon:Which one you have downloaded?

Comment: you mean Windows Intel Itanium?

Comment: @jon:Which one you have downloaded?

Comment: download this: :Windows x86 76.66 MB jdk-6u25-windows-i586.exe

Comment: @Jon: Error comes because your pc doesn't support 64 bits. You should download jdk6u25-windows-i586.exe

Comment: ok please advise after i installed the jdk this is come in place the jre or addtional to jre?

Comment: and what the diff why need jdk/

Comment: @Jon: You must have a copy of the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) on your system to run Java applications and applets. To develop Java applications and applets, you need the JDK (Java Development Kit), which includes the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go to java.sun.com (or oracle.com now) and follow the download & installation instruction. In the title of your question you write you are using 32-bit WinXP - then you want this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/, select JDK, select Windows x86.

JDK is always coming with its own JRE. That does not mean you need to remove your JRE before installing JDK, you can keep it, if you wish.

btw 1.6.0_05 is quite old you should consider update.